# How to retrieve youtube videos more than 500 using youtube rest api

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using this api https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=skateboarding+dog&start-index=1&max-results=10  to get the data, i am incresing the start-index parameter dynamically to get the next results. The problem is , i am able to receive 500 records but after that it is showing an exception saying "You cannot request beyond item 500."

Comment: Sounds like the REST API doesn't let you get more than 500 items....

Comment: Oh god, What should i do now?? Please help me out

Comment: I don't think it is possible, unfortunately.  Even through the Youtube website you can only access up to 1000 (50 pages of 20 results/page) and even those don't look very complete.  Once you go past page 30 (clicking) it just shows the same two videos.

Comment: Now what should i tell to my client...Sir. Is there any better way to get more than 500 videos

Comment: I don't see a way to do so.

Comment: Can you pelase give me a suggestion what to inform